# SQL Self Join to compare data different by days

Tags: sql, oracle, join, gaps-and-islands

I want to compare product different by days. The goal is to get difference between day1 and day2, day2 and day3 so on and so on.

```
Product  EventTime
X1       T1
X2       T1
X1       T2
X3       T2
X4       T10
```

Notes

- The event time is not liner it could be day1 day 2 and then day 10)
- The product is presented by multiple attributes but for showing the problem I used 1 field

Expected Result

```
Product  Action   EventTime
X1       Added    T1
X2       Added    T1
X2       Removed  T2
X3       Added    T2
X1       Removed  T10
X3       Removed  T10
X4       Added    T10
```

My idea is to give row number to those record and do a full outer join to find difference but I am not able to get the correct result.

My thought process - Let's give rank by event time.

```
Product  EventTime  RNK
X1       T1         1
X2       T1         1
X1       T2         2
X3       T2         2
X4       T10        3
```

if we do

```
select 
  * 
from 
    dataset d1 
full join 
    dataset d2
        on d1.product = d2.product
        and d1.RNK = d2.RNK - 1
where
    d1.product is null or d2.product is null
```

It doesn't give me the correct result. but if I clean the data first to make it

```
Product  EventTime  RNK
--------------------- X1       T1         1 (cross out)
----------------------X2       T1         1
X1       T2         2
X3       T2         2
X4       T10        3 

Product  EventTime  RNK
X1       T1         1
X2       T1         1
X1       T2         2
X3       T2         2
-------------------- X4       T10        3  (cross out)
```

And we do full join with above data set. I will get the correct result but the performance is slow. basically I removed the first rank and last rank.

Any ideas for get diff between 2 sets by day sequence?

Comment: I don't follow the logic.  Can you explain?

Comment: Yes. I have product data by each day. I want to compare day 1 product with day2, day2 product with day3 so on and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmmm . . . this looks like a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can get the time periods for each product using:

```
select product, min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by time) as seqnum_p
      from t
     ) t
group by product, (seqnum_p - seqnum);
```

Getting the removal time is a little tricker . . . you need to use `lead()` and some fancy aggregation:

```
select product, min(time), max(time),
       max(next_time) keep (dense_rank first over order by time desc) as next_time
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by time) as seqnum_p,
             min(time) over (order by time range between '1' second following and unbounded following) as next_time
      from t
     ) t
group by product, (seqnum_p - seqnum);
```

This may be sufficient for what you want.  But you can unpivot:

```
with cte as (
      select product, min(time) as min_time, 
             max(next_time) keep (dense_rank first over order by time desc) as next_time
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by time) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by product order by time) as seqnum_p,
                   min(time) over (order by time range between '1' second following and unbounded following) as next_time
            from t
           ) t
      group by product, (seqnum_p - seqnum)
     )
select product, 'Added', min_time
from cte
union all
select product 'Removed', next_time
from cte;
```

Comment: lol. Thanks for the solution. I think this is a bit hard to understand. Would my idea full outer join work? basically I was trying to do a join between day1 and day2, day2 and day3 ..

Comment: It look like you are missing some syntax in the `max() keep` function?  `dense_rank` `first` or `last`?  And `over` (what)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is consider it a "sparse data" problem.  That is, you have time events, but not every product is represented at every event.

A partitioned outer join can fill in the sparse data, resulting in a data set where every product is represented at every time.  Then, you can more easily see what was added and removed at each time.

```
with event_table (product, event_time) as 
( SELECT 'X1',  trunc(sysdate)+1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X2',  trunc(sysdate)+1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'X1',  trunc(sysdate)+2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'X3',  trunc(sysdate)+2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
  SELECT 'X4',  trunc(sysdate)+10 FROM DUAL ),
  -- solution begins here
  -- start by getting a distinct list of event times
  distinct_times as ( SELECT DISTINCT event_time FROM event_table ),
  -- Next, do a partitioned right join to ensure that every product is represented at every event time.  If the row is sparse data that was added by the right join, et.event_time will be null.
  -- We use the lag() function to see what the product looked like at the last event and
  -- compare with the current event.
  -- NULL -> NULL ==> no change
  -- NOT NULL -> NOT NULL ==> no change
  -- NULL -> NOT NULL ==> added
  -- NOT NULL -> NULL ==> removed
  sparse_data_filled as (
select dt.event_time, et.product,
case when lag(et.event_time ) over ( partition by et.product order by dt.event_time ) is null then
          -- product wasn't present during last event
          case when et.event_time is null then
            -- product still is not present
            null  -- no change
          else
            -- product is present now and was not before
            'Added'
          end
    else
      -- product was present during last event
      case when et.event_time is null then
        -- product is no longer present
          'Removed'
       else
         -- product is still present
         null   -- no change
      end
    end message
from event_table et partition by (product) 
right join distinct_times dt on et.event_time = dt.event_time )
SELECT * from sparse_data_filled
-- filter out the non-changes
where message is not null
order by event_time, product
;
```

> ```
> +------------+---------+---------+
> | EVENT_TIME | PRODUCT | MESSAGE |
> +------------+---------+---------+
> | 07-AUG-20  | X1      | Added   |
> | 07-AUG-20  | X2      | Added   |
> | 08-AUG-20  | X2      | Removed |
> | 08-AUG-20  | X3      | Added   |
> | 16-AUG-20  | X1      | Removed |
> | 16-AUG-20  | X3      | Removed |
> | 16-AUG-20  | X4      | Added   |
> +------------+---------+---------+
> ```

More compact, solution only version (no test data):

```
WITH 
  distinct_times as ( SELECT DISTINCT event_time FROM event_table ),
  changes as (
select dt.event_time, et.product,
case nvl2(et.event_time,1,0) - nvl2(lag(et.event_time ) over ( partition by et.product order by dt.event_time ),1,0)
       when +1 then 'Added'
       when -1 then 'Removed'
    end message
from event_table et partition by (product) 
right join distinct_times dt on et.event_time = dt.event_time )
SELECT * from changes
where message is not null
order by event_time, product
```